# show percent values instead of value

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

I am using the apexcharts to generate a "donut".
If I move the cursor over an element it will sho me the value of this element:

[image]

My code for this:

```
plotOptions: {
   pie: {
      donut: {
         labels: {
            show: true,
            value: {
               formatter: function (val) {
                  return val;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But how can I show the percent value of the element instead of the "normal value"?

Comment: yes I did. There is the section Donut Labels. But no information about the percent value. only the normal value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way is to calculate percentages yourself

```
formatter: function (val,chart) {
  if(val){
    let valPercent = val/chart.config.series.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)*100;
    return `${valPercent.toFixed(1)}%`; // or round with Math
  }
  return ''
}
```

Actualy there is array with percentage values `chart.globals.seriesPercent` but no `seriesIndex` is provided

Comment: you are the best ! Thanks !!